# Header file creating undeclared values

Tags: c, header, structure

I can't seem to wrap my head around this. I have the same setup for the other program which is a stack,push/pop and it's working perfectly. I'm receiving undeclared values first time used in function errors. Any help would be appreciated.

header file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int money();
void amortization();

typedef struct{
int principle;
int rate;
int payments;
} loan_t;
```

function code

```
int money(loan_t)
{
 printf("Please input the amount borrowed:");
 scanf("%d", &principle);
 printf("\nPlease input the Annual Interest Rate:");
 scanf("%d", &rate);
 printf("\nPlease input the number of monthly payments:\n");
 scanf("%d", &payments);
 return (principle,rate,payments);
 }
```

thank you!

Comment: Your `return` compiles because you're using the comma operator; your compiler might be warning you about 'left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect' or something similar.  If you declare local variables `principle`, `rate`, and `payments` (all of type `int`), and you define the return type as `loan_t`, you could use a compound literal in the `return` (using C99):  `return (loan_t){ principle, rate, payments };`.  Note that `"%lf"` reads a `double` value but the elements of the `loan_t` structure are all `int`; there's a problem there.

Comment: I didn't clarify what I'm trying to do, sorry. What my program is to do is take those values entered then use those in a different function to return an amortization table, which uses those values and calculates multiple formulas.

Comment: Note that you must specify a name for the parameter to `money()` (perhaps, but not sensibly, `int money(loan_t loan);`). Also note that your declaration in the header is not a prototype; it says nothing about the number or types of the arguments to the function.  You probably need either `loan_t money(void);` or `int money(loan_t *ploan);` as the function declaration, depending on how you want to fix your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
 int money(LOAN *var){
     printf("Please input the amount borrowed:");
     scanf("%lf", var->principle);
     printf("\nPlease input the Annual Interest Rate:");
     scanf("%lf", var->rate);
     printf("\nPlease input the number of monthly payments:\n");
     scanf("%lf", var->payments);
     return 0;
 }
```

change header to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct loan{
    double principle;
    double rate;
    double payments;
}LOAN;

int money(LOAN *var);
void amortization();
```

this means you will return a `loan_t` with the desirable values inside

edit: edited to suit you the best, not to the best practice as Jonathan Leffler recommended

declare a `LOAN variable;` inside `main()` and then call `money(&variable);`

Comment: I prefer the question's `loan_t` to your `LOAN_t`.  Both are dodgy in a POSIX environment where `_t` is reserved for the implementation to use.  If you pass `var` into `money()`, there's no need to return it; you could save the return value to indicate whether the reads were all successful (well, you could if you paid any attention to the return values from `scanf()`, which you should, of course.  Since the structure elements are all `int`, using `%lf` in the format is going to lead to problems.

Comment: I was testing the return that's why it's weird. Also, now I'm getting scode.c:15: error: parse error before '*' token scode.c:15: error: conflicting types for 'money'
loan.h:4: error: previous declaration of 'money' was here

Comment: In `scanf()`, `"%f"` is for `float`, `"%lf"` is for `double`, and `"%Lf"` is for `long double`.

Comment: @jonathan-leffler regarding that i just have to say i have a bad C book, it says there `float - %f,%e,%E` and `double - %f,%e,%E`

Comment: @mf_ thanks for the reply, I'm still receiving the parse error. Couldn't I just do this without a structure? It isn't required to be done this way, I just thought it would make the program shorter.

Comment: Double check what I said at the POSIX [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) description.  Then throw your book away.  Note that the rules for `printf()` are different from those for `scanf()`; what you said would apply to `printf()`, though the reasons are modestly complex.

Comment: Better: `LOAN variable;` and simply call `money(&variable);` -- use dynamic allocation for big or variable size objects, not for little fixed size items like a loan structure.  Also note that if you're always going to return 0 from a function, it is better to make it a `void` function so that callers do not have to waste time checking for the 'correct' status from the function.  Or, detect I/O errors, format errors or EOF in the function, returning EOF when one occurs.  Then it is sensible to return 0 on 'no error' and the caller should check the result every time.

Comment: jonathan-leffler did the thinking, i only did verbose + learned with it

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provided, it looks like `principle`, `rate`, and `payments` are all undeclared in `money`.  You also provide a type as a parameter without a parameter name in `money`.

edit: as noted by the other answerer, return is fishy as well.

I am not able to test this myself right now, but try:

```
loan_t money(loan_t loan)
{
 printf("Please input the amount borrowed:");
 scanf("%lf", &(loan.principle));
 printf("\nPlease input the Annual Interest Rate:");
 scanf("%lf", &(loan.rate));
 printf("\nPlease input the number of monthly payments:\n");
 scanf("%lf", &(loan.payments));
 return loan;
 }
```

Comment: The is no point in passing in the `loan_t loan` by value since you'll have to return the new value.  You should just take no arguments, make `loan_t loan;` into a local variable, check that the `scanf()` calls work, and return `loan` at the end (as you do).

Comment: Still giving errors, I'm probably implementing the header wrong for this fix.